# How to use velocity toolbox in Struts 2?

Tags: java, struts2, velocity, velocity-tools

I use velocity1.6.4, velocity-tools1.4,  and struts2.3.15.2

in `struts.xml`:

```
<constant name="struts.velocity.toolboxlocation" value="/WEB-INF/toolbox.xml" />
```

**in `toolbox.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<toolbox>
    <tool>
        <key>date</key>
        <scope>application</scope>
        <class>
            org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.ComparisonDateTool
        </class>
        <parameter name="format" value="yyyy-MM-dd" />
        <parameter name="depth" value="2" />
        <parameter name="skip" value="month" />
    </tool>
    <tool>
        <key>controlUtil</key>
        <scope>application</scope>
        <class>com.quangao.bible.webapp.util.ControlUtil</class>
    </tool>
</toolbox>
```

**the `ControlUtil.java` is**

```
public class ControlUtil {
    
    public static List<Keyword> getKeywords(ServletContext servletContext) {
        System.out.println("------");
        KeywordManager keywordManager = (KeywordManager) getBean(
                servletContext, "keywordManager");
        try {
            List<Keyword> value = keywordManager.getKeywords();
            System.out.println(value);
            if (value != null && value.size() > 5) {
                return value.subList(0, 5);
            } else {
                return value;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and in `index.vm` I try to user the method `getKeywords()` in `ControlUtil`

```
#set($keyWords=$controlUtil.getKeywords($session.servletContext))
```

It is don't word, the right way of `System.out.println("------");` in method `getKeywords()` should print ,but it not

why I can't reach method `getKeywords()` in `ControlUtil` from vm file，please help me ！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no any reason to pass servlet context via parameter. You can simplify code

```
#set ($keyWords = $controlUtil.keywords)
```

But the tool should initialize `servletContext` property

```
public class ControlUtil {

    private ServletContext servletContext;

    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
       this.servletContext = servletContext; 
    }

    public static List<Keyword> getKeywords() {
        System.out.println("------");
        KeywordManager keywordManager = (KeywordManager) getBean(
                servletContext, "keywordManager");
        try {
            List<Keyword> value = keywordManager.getKeywords();
            System.out.println(value);
            if (value != null && value.size() > 5) {
                return value.subList(0, 5);
            } else {
                return value;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It still does not work，I think my configuration is wrong or I user the wrong version of velocity and velocity-tool  ，but I don't know where ，

Comment: download latest versions, velocity tools 2.0 AFAIK